# Different size of the same instance of flatbuffers structure of primitives

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

Consider the following `flatbuffers` scheme

```
namespace app;

table App
{
    value: ubyte;
}

root_type App;
```

When I try to instantiate the structure with `value = 0`, and then get the size of the buffer, it gives `12 bytes`, but when I instantiate it with `value = 1 (or any non-zero value)`, the size is `20 bytes`. I'm not sure if this is the correct behavior. I'd expect the primitive types to be consistent in their size.

For demonstration, check out this [sample repository](https://github.com/arsdever/flatbuffers_issue_demo)

P.S. I'm using the scheme in `C++` program, therefore I'm putting the `C++` tag on the question. I'm not sure if the same behavior is present for other languages.

Comment: @arsdever Provide a minimal complete program. Your provided code does not make a sense.

Comment: Yes, default values are not stored. Read https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_internals.html if you want to understand why it is 12 and 20.

Comment: @Aardappel "Yes, default values are not stored." does this mean, that there is no way to ensure, that the size of a structure/table will be exactly `k bytes`? We are talking about structures containing only defined size data (integers, floats, but not strings or vectors).

Comment: @arsdever no there is not.